# sep option in read table data input

Tags: r

I am reading data via the read.table function in R. How can I deal with varying field separations? i.e., one OR two whitespaces between columns of the table.

Answer (score 0):

Number of white spaces do not matter. See the example below:

```
ddf = read.table(text="
 a b
 1 2
 3 4
", header=T)

ddf
  a b
1 1 2
2 3 4


ddf2 = read.table(text="
 a           b
 10          20
 30          40
 50          60
 ", header=T)
ddf2
   a  b
1 10 20
2 30 40
3 50 60
```

Comment: Thanks - I should have read the documentation, it is written there. I still wonder how the algorithm looks, though.